# Insert into a javascript array the result of a query using ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I want to insert the result of a query into a javascript array.

I have a problem: into the result could be HTML Tags, so i try to Encode the string.
But it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
Response.Write "<script type='text/javascript'>"& vbCrLf
Response.Write "var myArr = new Array();"
z=0     
Do While not rsScadenze.EOF


If (rsScadenze("scadenza")<> "") Then

    encodeString =Server.HtmlEncode(rsScadenze("testo"))

    Response.Write "myArr["& z &"]=('"& encodeString &"');"& vbCrLf

    z=z+1

End If
rsScadenze.MoveNext
Loop

Response.Write "</script>"
rsScadenze.close
```

How can i do?

Thanks for helping me

Thank you for the accurate answer. 
I made the changes but it doesn't still work, i'm going crazy. The HTML don't generate nothing, only a blank sheet with no errors.
So i looked the source code of the page, that my code generates:

```
<script>
var myArr = new Array();
myArr[0]=('&lt;div style=&quot;text-align: justify&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=& quot;font-size: 11pt&quot;&gt;Per i contribuenti che effettuano operazioni con operatori economici aventi sede, residenza o domicilio negli Stati o territori dei Paesi c.d. &amp;ldquo;&lt;i&gt;black-list&lt;/i&gt;&amp;rdquo; scade oggi il termine di presentazione degli elenchi riepilogativi delle operazioni effettate nel mese precedente, per i contribuenti tenuti a questo adempimento con cadenza mensile.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');
document.write (myArr[0]);
... and so on, until the last element of my array
```

I tried to change the content of encodeString writing manually a string (encodeString ="..."), and in this case the code works well.

Why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aURmv/ - seems like it is writing content.  There must be something else going on if you're only getting a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a few things...

first, break the string that starts with [script] into something like this

`response.write "<scr" & "ipt" & ...`

asp does not like to see the word "< script >" being response.written!

do the same to the closer

`response.write "</sc" & "ript>"`

using the script and /script like that confuses the asp.dll.

this is a generic tip and so always do it the way I suggest it.

as to your code, you can try this;

change 
`if rsScadenze("scadenza")<> "") Then`

to 
`if "" & rsScadenze("scadenza")<> "" ) Then`
this way, you can catch the nulls too

change 
`encodeString =Server.HtmlEncode(rsScadenze("testo"))`
to
`encodeString = Server.HtmlEncode(rsScadenze("testo"))`

`encodeString = replace(encodeString,vbcrlf," ",1,-1,1)`

`encodeString = replace(encodeString,vbcr," ",1,-1,1)`

`encodeString = replace(encodeString,vblf," ",1,-1,1)`

`'the above 3 lines would take care of any issue with line breaks

`encodeString = replace(encodeString,"""","&quot;",1,-1,1)`

`'the above line would take care of any occurrences of "`

the rest of your code looks fine...

try these recommendations and let us know, but this time include the html ( or the errors ) generated pls.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the array element name as well:

```
Response.Write "myArr['"& z &"']=('"& encodeString &"');"& vbCrLf
```

Comment: i've tried to quote the array elemen but it doesn't still work. Can be the error into the Server.HTMLEncode?